# Complex sorting in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

In my application there is a `Membership` model with attribute `username_or_email`, which is used to invite users to system. When user accepts invitation, the `Membership` object is updated with a relation to new `User` object, who has a `name` attribute. Now I would like to sort every `Membership` objects in a single view, and show it like this:

1. If there is already user registered, show name attribute from joined `User` object.
2. If there is only invited user, show `username_or_email` attribute.

How can I easily sort it alphabetically by two columns?

Comment: I was not able to make it work on database level, and moved it to sort_by method

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you might do this (let's assume using PostgreSQL)

A scope on Membership that handles the query

```
# class Membership
 def self.ordered_by_formatted_name
   joins("LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = memberships.user_id").
     order("COALESCE(users.name, memberships.username_or_email)")
 end
```

An instance method on Membership for the display logic

```
# class Membership
def formatted_name
  user ? user.name : username_or_email
end
```

Example usage

```
@memberships = Membership.ordered_by_formatted_name.preload(:user)

<% @memberships.each do |m| %>
  <%= m.formatted_name %>
<% end %>
```